# Unity hierarchical injection

Tags: inheritance, inversion-of-control, unity-container

Please help me to solve the following goal:
I have interface IRepository that defines the property Context, as a sample:

```
interface IRepository
{
   IContext Context { get; set; }
}

interface IOne : IRepository
{
}

interface ITwo : IRepository
{
}
```

the property Context in implementation have DependencyAttribyte and all implementation registered as in following sample:

```
container.RegisterType<IOne, One>();
container.RegisterType<ITwo, Two>();
container.RegisterType<IContext, Context>();
```

I want to resolve implementation "Two" from implementation "One" with inheritance of value of property "Context";

as a sample:

```
public class One : IOne
{
   [Dependency]
   public IContext Context { get; set; }

   [Dependency]
   public IUnityContainer Container { get; set; }

   public void Test1()
   {
       Context = new Context();
       var two = Container.Resolve<ITwo>();

       // I want that these values would been equal
       Assert.AreEqual(Context, two.Context);
   }
}
```

If you will able to show another way how to resolve implementations with value inheritance then it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `PerResolveLifetimeManager`. It acts just as a transient lifestyle, but the instance will be reused thoughout the object graph. For this to work however, you will have to replace the call to `container.Resolve` from your `Test1` method. Always prefer constructor injection over property injection and prevent calling into the container from within your classes. This way of coding is called the [service locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can register `IContext` using the ContainerControlledLifetimeManager. Thus every call to `Resolve<IContext>` will return the same instance.

Another way is to [register an instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.unitycontainer.registerinstance.aspx) of IContext.

Comment: `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` creates a singleton. I'm not sure that's what the OP wants. Seems to me that he want the 'per resolve' or 'lifetime scoped' lifestyle.